# How to append a column from one csv file to second csv (with different indices)

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am working on concatenating many csv files together and want to take one column, from a multicolumn csv, and append it as a new column in a second csv. The problem is that the columns have different numbers of rows so the new column that I am adding to the existing csv gets cut short once the row index from the existing csv is reached.

I have tried to read in the new column as a second dataframe and then add that dataframe as a new column to the existing csv.

```
df = pd.read_csv("Existing CSV.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("New CSV.csv", usecols = ['Desired Column'])
df["New CSV"] = df2
```

"Existing CSV" has 1200 rows of data while "New CSV" has 1500 rows. When I run the code, the 'New CSV" column is added to "Existing CSV", however, only the first 1200 rows of data are included.

Ideally, all 1500 rows from "New CSV" will be included and the 300 rows missing from "Existing CSV" will be left blank.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `read_csv` gives the resulting DataFrame an integer index, so I can think of a couple of options to try.

#### Setup

```
df = pd.read_csv("Existing CSV.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("New CSV.csv", usecols = ['Desired Column'])
```

#### Method 1: `join`

```
df = df.join(df2['Desired Column'], how='right')
```

#### Method 2: `reindex_like` and `assign`

```
df = df.reindex_like(df2).assign(**{'Desired Column': df2['Desired Column']})
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! I tried these and they aren't seeming to work. Instead of appending the data as a new column, it places it in the existing column or doesn't append at all.Unfortunately I am new to this so do not really understand how to explain the errors better or troubleshoot well

Comment: @Matt, sorry to hear. Would you be able to post a few lines from `df` and `df2` with different lengths, as well as the expected output of the concatenation? You could either edit this question, or even post a new one for greater visibility.